# XCode Source Control - Discard Changes Deleted imported files

Tags: ios, xcode, version-control, spritebuilder

I am doing a game for iPhone and iPad using SpriteBuilder. SpriteBuilder makes a couple of files in the same folder as the XCode project. I was using Source Control and I just made a commit, then I changed a little bit of the code in the XCode (I changed nothing of the spritebuilder files) and then I changed my mind and I wanted to go back to the commit I made. So I did source control -> discard changes. The XCode successfully replaced the new code with the old code but it erased most of my SpriteBuilder files!!

How do I get my SpriteBuilder files again?

[image: Screenshot of the last commit. You can see that xcode knows when the spritebuilder files are changed so it should keep them no?]

Screenshot of the last commit. You can see that xcode knows when the spritebuilder files are changed so it should keep them no?

Comment: What SpriteBuilder files? The ones in the Published-iOS folder are recreated when publishing. Also note that Discard All Changes in Xcode does just that, discarding ALL changes whether they were made in Xcode or SpriteBuilder. If you didn't have your SB changes checked in you have lost them for good, unless you were making regular backups with Time Machine.

Comment: It deleted most of the .ccb files and some images. Since I did the last commit on XCode I didn't alter any SpriteBuilder files I just changed some code on XCode.

Comment: Were the files in Published-iOS or in the 'SpriteBuilder Resources' folder? If you can reproduce the issue it would be worth reporting it as a bug, specifically if the Xcode builtin source control can lead to a loss of files in an SB project that would be a serious issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the way Xcode calls Git appears to do this. All may not be lost, however. Check the trash for your missing files.

Comment: I lost 2 new files (marked w/'A') this way. Not in the trash & nowhere on the Mac. Fortunately can reproduce easily. BAD implementation of git 'discard changes' cmd in Xcode 14.3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Open the file you wish to bring back your lost changes to using TextEdit.
3. Go to File -> Revert To -> Browse All Versions...
4. Scroll through the available versions. Hopefully you will have many available to choose from.
5. Select a version and hit Restore.
6. Follow 1-5 for all necessary files.
7. Launch Xcode. You should now see the M next to these files in Project Navigator indicating they include uncommited changes (the changes you previously discarded).